# Get all values except one in constant time and linear space?

Tags: c#, .net, algorithm, data-structures

I have thousands of `Entry` objects, and have a method `GetAllExcept(int entryId)`, which returns a `List<Entry>` of all objects except one with the key specified. This method will be called multiple times so it should be optimized for read. I also have memory constraints so linear space complexity is better.

I can traverse the object list each time but it will be in `O(n)` time.
I can preprocess to use a `Dictionary<int, List<Entry>>` that maps an entryId to `List` of `Entries` that don't have that key but it will be `O(n2)` space complexity.

Anyone has a better solution?

Comment: What type does `GetAllExcept(int entryId)` return?

Comment: if you want to *collect* the result in a new object you will have the `O(n)` time no matter what - so the only alternative if you are only interested in space is returning an object with just the information (the original `IEnummerable` and the *missing* index) and just use it when you enumerate the thing)

Comment: I just update the return type, it should be `List` or `IEnumerable`
@Carsten hmm, so it sounds unavoidable after all :(

Comment: Constructing a new `List` is always going to be O(n), as @Carsten said. If it has to return `List<Entry>` and not `IEnumerable<Entry>`, then that is your answer.

Comment: With the magic of deferred execution, simply returning `_listOfAllEntries.Where(t=>t.Id != entryId)` will give you an `IEnumerable<Entry>` in constant time and space that can be iterated in O(n) (of course).

Comment: @Blorgbeard that basically what I meant with the second part ;)

Comment: OK thanks guys, I will go with that

Comment: You are doing a conversion from object to List<Entry> which is always going to take 0(n).  Skipping one member means you are performing 0(n) comparisons.  So memory is List<n-1> and execution time is n * (conversion time + comparison time).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about the `Entry` object, the number of time the call will be made compared to the size of the `List<Entry>` object. So you will have to confirm if my suggestion works for your situation.

Let me demonstrate a technique using integers, you can hopefully apply that to Entry objects. I will assume you have a List where EntryId is an integer. Let's say your `List<EntryId>` has thousands of elements and you will need to call `GetAllExcept(int entryId)` a million times.

You should store your collection of ListId in a slightly different data structure. Imagine a sorted list that is broken down into reasonably sized (fits into cache line) chunks, each chunk being put in a bucket; something like a jagged array `EntryId[][]` or `List<List<EntryId>>`.

So, even though you will still have O(n) performance, you will reduce the value of the multiplier by a good margin. This data-structure will work better with branch predictor and also processor caching.

Answer (score 0):

You can keep two lists, one of size `N`, one of size `N-1`.  Also, keep track of which item is missing from the smaller list.

When you are asked for a different "except-one" list, swap the item missing from the smaller list with the item you are now being asked to exclude.

Voila, O(1) time and O(n) space requirements.  (Except for the initial setup in O(n) time, but that should still result in O(1) amortized time).

However, it isn't quite that easy.  You have to find the item to remove from the smaller list in O(1) time, and knowing the index in the bigger list isn't enough, since the small list gets shuffled by this series of replacements.  So you'll need an additional array mapping global index to small-list index.  Maintaining this list has the same complexity: O(n) space, O(1) update, O(n) setup time.

The consumer also needs to promise not to overwrite the small list, so you can reuse it for the next call.  And of course, the subsequent call DOES overwrite the small list, so the consumer has to use the list immediately; he isn't allowed to save it for future use.  And of course, the list returned from `GetAllExcept` has the right set of objects but not in their original order.